# mysql where session is a varchar

Tags: php, mysql, session, where-clause

I have a easy select query

```
$sql = "SELECT `testName`, `percentile`, `dateTaken`, `correct`, `total`, `timeSpent` FROM `results` WHERE `uniID` = 5 AND `userID` = $_SESSION[userid] ORDER BY  `dateTaken` ASC";
```

userID is set to

> varchar 250

the query works fine if I am looking for a userID that is a number but when looking for a userID that is letters it returns blank.
Is there a simple reason for this ?

Thanks

Comment: check for errors via php and the query. String values require them to be quoted. Plus, you're leaving that open to an sql injection. Use a prepared statement.

Comment: Because character values need to be wrapped in quotes.  If you replace your SQL injection vulnerability with a query parameter this problem becomes moot anyway.

Comment: @David, thanks whats the best way to do this

Comment: @BenjaminOats: The primary term you're searching for is "prepared statement".  Both the `mysqli` and `PDO` data access libraries support those and include examples of them in their documentation.  In a broad sense, what you want to do is avoid using variables directly in SQL queries.  Instead, you would use a "query parameter" and use the variable to "bind" that parameter as a separate call to that data access library before executing the query.

Comment: @David thanks ill research "prepared statement" +1

Comment: done and solved, thanks David